# Написать метод, который принимает неопределенное число строк в параметры

Tags: java

Есть задание где надо: Написать метод, который принимает неопределенное 
число строк в параметры.
В методе строки должны добавляться в объект класса `StringBuilder` через разделитель "\n".
Метод возвращает строку, которая получилась 
после конкатенации.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}

static String str(String... s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

        sb.append(s[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

у меня не получается ввести данные в массив `String s;`, когда пишу `s = sc.next()`; выдает ошибку:

> string cannot be converted to string

Помогите решить проблему и вообще правильно ли я делаю по заданию )

Comment: А зачем тебе сканнер, если по заданию в метод передается массив строк. Тебе нужно просто эти строки запихать в стринг билдер. Поясни, для чего ты добавлял сканнер? Или задача была наполнить стринг билдер с инпута?

Comment: хотел для себя сделать сканнер что бы усложнить задачу )

Comment: @ConstantinNaumov,  как-раз сканер и поможет собрать массив случайно вбитых строк, чтобы потом отправить его в метод для разбора и т. д., не нужно ТС вводить в заблуждение, все он делает верно.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Евгений,

Скорее всего `Scanner` здесь уместней использовать в `main` методе. Например в коде ниже приложение будет ждать ввода строчек, разделенных запятой, а по нажатию `Enter` будет передавать образовавшийся массив в метод `str`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static final String STRING_SEPARATOR = ",";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] split = sc.nextLine().split(STRING_SEPARATOR);
        System.out.println(str(split));
    }

    static String str(String... s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            sb.append(s[i]).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: Лучше построчно разделять, а не через `,` - ибо строка может быть предложением и со знаками препинания.

Answer (score 0):

А точно нужно читать `stdin` при помощи `Scanner`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = str("a", "b", "c");
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    static String str(String... s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0)
                sb.append("\n");
            sb.append(s[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```